# Save a modied FASTA file with Biopython

Tags: python, string, sequence, biopython, dna-sequence

I have used Biopython to remove some sequences due to they are too short.
However, I don't know how to save the printed new sequences in a txt file.

This is the code that I have:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
```

`for seq_record in SeqIO.parse("aminoacid_example.txt", "fasta"):`

```
if len(seq_record.seq)>=30:
    print(">",seq_record.id)
    print(seq_record.seq)
```

Output:

">NP_414584.1

MNTFSQVWVFSDTPSRLPELMNGAQALANQINTFVLNDADGAQAIQLGANHVWKLN

"> NP_414563.1

MASVSISCPSCSATDGVVRNGKSTAGHQRYLCSHCRKTWQLQFTYTASQPGTHQKIIDMAMNG

"> NP_414564.1

MANIKSAKKRAIQSEKARKHNASRRSMMRTFIKKVYAAIEAGDKAAAQKAFNEMQPIVDRQAAKGLIHK

How can I save this sequences in a txt file?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should go something like this:

```
text_list=[]
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse("aminoacid_example.txt", "fasta"):
    if len(seq_record.seq)>=30:
        elem1=">"+seq_record.id
        elem2=seq_record.seq
        text_list.extend([elem1, elem2])
with open('filetowrite.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(text_list)
```

This would create a list with all the elements that you want, then it would write them to a file 'filetowrite.txt' (or however you want to call it), with each value on a new line.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Was a good solution for my problem!